# Python. Скрипт для отправки данных для регистрации аккаунтов

Tags: python, веб-программирование, shell, usercontrol

Всем привет. Есть такая задача:
у нас есть xls/csv файл, который содержит имена, фамилия, даты рождения и тд.
**1)** нужно считать данные и завести их в подходящую структуру данных.Так же сгенерировать пароль(в питоне это не проблема) и добавить в эту структуру данных.
**2)** после чего нужно передать данные в соответстующие поля в веб-интерфейсе(тоесть есть сайт для регистрации аккаунтов, и считываем данные со структуры и кладем в нужные поля на страницу)
**3)** при перенесении данных в веб-интерфейс нужно обеспечить проверку логичности, валидности данных(тоесть елементарную проверку на правильность ввода данных)
**В конечном итоге должна получится программа, на вход которой подается файлик с данными(+ ссылка на форму, зависит уже от деталей реализации) и она сама перекидывает в форму, для возможности автоматизированной регистрации нескольких сотен или больше пользователей.**

[image: вот в таком виде]

Comment: Спасибо. Будем знать, что есть такая задача.

Comment: Какое хорошее тестовое задание. Вам скорее всего на биржу фриланса